Proving Optimal Loss Analogous to PCA
Suppose we have a data distribution on $x ∈ R^d$. Suppose $E_x[x] = 0$, and let $Σ = E_x[xx^T]$ be the covariance of x. Let $Σ = USU^T$ be the spectral decomposition of Σ, with U orthonormal and S diagonal (ordered by magnitude). We use the loss:
$L1(A, B) := E_x [||f_{A,B} (x) − x||_2^2]$
Let $U_k ∈ R^{d×k}$ be the first k columns of U . That is, $U_k$ is the matrix of the top-k eigenvectors of Σ. Prove that the optimal loss L1 is achieved for $f_{A,B} (x) = U_kU^T_kx$.
That is: $A∗, B∗ ∈ argmin_{A,B}L_1(A, B) ⇒ f_{A∗,B∗} (x) = U_kU^T_kx$.
I've tried setting x to be a linear combination of the eigenvectors and saw the optimal loss would be the norm of the sum of the linear combination with just eigenvectors k+1 and higher. There's a hint to base this on Eckart-Young-Mirsky theorem so I've been trying to show a lower bound with general A,B would be higher than this but can't seem to make any progress.
Any hints/tips/a solution would be greatly appreciated. If you also had some references I could look through for further reading on the topic (and even optimization/applied linear algebra) would be great as well!
